# How to trigger snapshot build on successful release build?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, release, snapshot

Once release build is success and the jar file is uploaded to artifactory, next snapshot build should be triggered automatically. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your upload task is called `uploadToArtifactory` and your snapshot build task is called `snapshotBuild`, you could solve this by adding something like this to your build script:

```
uploadToArtifactory.finalizedBy snapshotBuild
```

Comment: @Sandeep: I know my answer is not terribly specific but so is your question … Please update your question if you need anything more specific. Otherwise I’d be happy if my answer was still useful!